# What is the alternative of Bitcoin-RPC-Client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am implementing Bitcoin-RPC-Client for web application but I found bitcoin-RPC-client is better than bitcoinj and what are the advantages and disadvanatges of Bitcoin-RPC-client.